# styled components targeting nested elements with Template strings

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I would like to target specific elements inside my styled component that would work with object notation.

```
styled(Grid)`
  background: #2c353d;
  border-radius: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  display: flex;

  '& > div': {
    padding: 20px;
  }
`
```

How am I able to target the `div` inside the `Grid` whilst using Template strings?

So css selector would be: `div > div`

Comment: That's a great statement. What's the question, though?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion I will update the question. But I was surprised it was difficult to understand the question I am a little shocked :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple `div` inside of the template string is enough to target all `div` elements inside of the Grid component.

```
styled(Grid)`
  background: #2c353d;
  border-radius: 14px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  display: flex;

  div {
    padding: 20px;
  }
`
```

Comment: Thanks very much!! Indeed, by removing the quotes using the `&` worked.